# Бот игнорирует команды

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Я создаю бота на языке Python с помощью библиотеки `telebot` (`pyTelegramBotAPI`), в нем юзер например заполняет анкету и все это делается через `register_next_step_handler`, но если написать команду например `/start` то бот игнорирует её, нужно в каждой команде сделать проверку по типу

```py
if message.text == "/start":
   start_message(message)
```

Или есть другой способ?

Answer (score 2):

Во первых, для обработки команд не нужно использовать if. Во вторых, не нужно в начало команды добавлять знак /.
Команды ловятся с помощью аргумента декоратора:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands="start")
def start(message):
    pass
```

Рекомендую почитать документацию библиотеки pytelegrambotapi перед тем как приступать, иначе будете наступать на элементарные грабли.

Comment: Я говорю про то что есть другие функции кроме этих декоротаров. В эти функции бот заходит через register_next_step_handler и в них принимается текст, но если нажать /start то ничего не произойдёт